# BASH How to loop through directories and extract filenames

Tags: bash

If I have the following folder structure, how would I loop through each directory, extract the file names in each directory, and get the first bit of text in the array?

```
Folder1
    File1-test
    File2-test
Folder2
   File3-test
   File4-test
```

I need File1, File2, File3 etc.

Comment: `find . -type f -exec blah {}  \;` check man page for help `man find`. search for `-exec` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name "*-test" | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sed 's/-test//'
```

Look for all files match `*-test` pattern, then split path using `/` and print only the last field, then  remove the `-test` part.

Alternative method

```
find . -type f -name "*-test" | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | awk -F- '{print $1}'
```